# Where can I ask about programming naming and semantics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

While programming I often have naming questions, such as "how do I name [thing]  in a descriptive but succinct way? Is there already an accepted terms for this/an alternative to [name]?" (Thing could be a programming concept, a function, a class, a variable)

Is Stack Overflow the right place to ask these naming/semantics questions?

I would like to be able to get meaningful answers, not just "Name it [name] and call it a day."

Comment: Codereview often supplies naming suggestions. But suggestions for naming a single function/variable is boring.

Comment: I answered a [question about naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053062/3648282) on SO, before it was closed as opinion based; so you might want to try a different programming site. A complete general answer would be lengthy, as you can see from the simple question that I answered.

Comment: Related [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) --- RedKnight91, Rubén's comment is a suggestion; mine is automatically generated, from the review queue.

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." – Phil Karlton & Leon Bambrick

Comment: I would suggest the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/), where you can describe what you want to express with the name and then ask if there is a short adjective/noun/verb expressing this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) could be the right place to make questions about "naming conventions" to be used in the software developing process. Here are some related tags

- [coding-standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-standards)
- [coding-style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)
- [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming)
- [naming-standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming-standards)

Also you could ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the naming conventions used in a specific piece of code. Here are some sample questions

- [Analyzing naming conventions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92506/91556)
- [Class naming conventions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/42546/91556)

Related

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)

Comment: Key with Code Review is that there has to be existing code before it's reviewable. Don't abstract other parts away either, and don't complain if the reviews focus on different problems first. If you're more interested in naming things that haven't been written yet or don't care about the rest of the overall code quality, Software Engineering is a better fit.

Comment: Software Engineering can be the right place for such questions, but don't be surprised/angry if a naming question gets closed quickly. That should typically be interpreted as "we don't care what name you use. Just pick one and be done with it."

Answer (score 3):

"What do I name something" would be a primarily opinion based question and no stack site would allow it.

What you name something is up to you. There are books that talk about naming conventions but it's still up to you which books to read and whether to pay attention to anything they say.